# Integrating JaCoCo, Arquillian and REST Assured brings me a code coverage of 0%

Tags: java, maven, jboss-arquillian, jacoco, rest-assured

I'm using JaCoCo, Arquillian and rest-assured to test my RESTFul API. The problem is that I'm getting a 0% code coverage within my JaCoCo report. I'm using a maven profile for test cases, getting a wildfly instance, deploying it on JVM, deploying my API and then running the tests.

I've made some researches and reach the point where I know that JaCoCo must be running on same JVM where the .war file is running (What is my case).

As JaCoCo is on the same JVM, I thought the coverage wouldn't suffer any changes, but it brings me 0%.

Can anyone help me with this?

Follows my maven profile on pom.xml:

```
<profile>
        <id>test-postgresql</id>

        <properties>
            <datasource.driver>postgresql.jar</datasource.driver>
            <datasource.driverClass>org.postgresql.Driver</datasource.driverClass>
            <datasource.url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/security-test</datasource.url>
            <datasource.user>postgres</datasource.user>
            <datasource.password>a</datasource.password>
        </properties>

        <dependencies>
            <!-- WildFly Container Managed -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-managed</artifactId>
                <version>${wildfly.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

            <!-- PostgreSQL JDBC Driver -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
                <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                <version>${jdbc.postgresql.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <!-- Dependency Plugin -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${plugin.dependency.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <!-- Unpack WildFly -->
                        <execution>
                            <id>unpack-wildfly</id>
                            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>unpack</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <artifactItems>
                                    <artifactItem>
                                        <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>wildfly-dist</artifactId>
                                        <version>${wildfly.version}</version>
                                        <type>zip</type>
                                        <overWrite>false</overWrite>
                                        <outputDirectory>target</outputDirectory>
                                    </artifactItem>
                                </artifactItems>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>

                        <!-- Deploy JDBC Driver -->
                        <execution>
                            <id>copy-driver</id>
                            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>copy</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <artifactItems>
                                    <artifactItem>
                                        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                                        <version>${jdbc.postgresql.version}</version>
                                        <type>jar</type>
                                        <overWrite>false</overWrite>
                                        <outputDirectory>target/wildfly-${wildfly.version}/standalone/deployments</outputDirectory>
                                        <destFileName>${datasource.driver}</destFileName>
                                    </artifactItem>
                                </artifactItems>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>

                <!-- Skip Unit Tests -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${plugin.surefire.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <!-- Integration Tests -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${plugin.failsafe.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <argLine>${jacoco.agent.it.arg}</argLine>
                        <redirectTestOutputToFile>false</redirectTestOutputToFile>
                        <systemPropertyVariables>
                            <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                            <jboss.home>${project.basedir}/target/wildfly-${wildfly.version}</jboss.home>
                            <module.path>${project.basedir}/target/wildfly-${wildfly.version}/modules</module.path>
                        </systemPropertyVariables>
                        <skipTests>false</skipTests>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/test/**/*.java</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>integration-test</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>verify integration-test</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>verify</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>

                <!-- Liquibase Plugin (Drop Database) -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                    <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${liquibase.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <driver>${datasource.driverClass}</driver>
                        <url>${datasource.url}</url>
                        <username>${datasource.user}</username>
                        <password>${datasource.password}</password>
                        <promptOnNonLocalDatabase>false</promptOnNonLocalDatabase>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>drop-database</id>
                            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>dropAll</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>

                <!-- JaCoCo Plugin -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${plugin.jacoco.version}</version>
                    <dependencies>
                        <!-- JaCoCo -->
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                            <artifactId>org.jacoco.core</artifactId>
                            <version>${plugin.jacoco.version}</version>
                        </dependency>

                        <!-- Arquillian JaCoCo -->
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
                            <artifactId>arquillian-jacoco</artifactId>
                            <version>1.0.0.Alpha8</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                    <configuration>
                        <append>true</append>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>jacoco-agent</id>
                            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>prepare-agent-integration</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <destFile>${sonar.jacoco.itReportPath}</destFile>
                                <propertyName>jacoco.agent.it.arg</propertyName>
                                <append>true</append>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>

                        <execution>
                            <id>jacoco-report</id>
                            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>report-integration</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

Comment: What does your test class look like?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had to configure the JaCoCo agent when Arquillian started the container.
Actually, my jacoco plugin becomes:

pom.xml

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${plugin.jacoco.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>jacoco-prepare</id>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>prepare-agent-integration</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <propertyName>jacoco.agent</propertyName>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>jacoco-report</id>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>report-integration</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

In the arquillian.xml arguments, add the `${jacoco.agent}` variable at the end of "`javaVmArguments`" property. Like this:

```
<property name="javaVmArguments">-Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=10000 -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m ${arquillian.debug} ${jacoco.agent}</property>
```

Comment: Hi @jhonata.sobrinho, thanks so much for sharing your solution. I tried your suggestion, but my tests fail when I add `${arquillian.debug} ${jacoco.agent}` as you suggest. Any ideas why? Any chance we can see a larger portion of your pom?

The section where it fails outputs `Error: Could not find or load main class ${arquillian.debug}`

Comment: Sorry @FranciscoC. but I don't have access to the file anymore. I think you need to setup the full classpath on the properties section of the pom to the JaCoCo agent and Arquillian Debug classes, right? I'm not sure how it was set, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @jhonata.sobrinho, I gave up on trying this a while ago, I'll try again using your suggestions later.